# How to POST/PUT scraped data to RESTful API

Tags: python, django, scrapy, tastypie

I have a scraper that outputs JSON. I would like to programmatically read this output (e.g. on a daily basis) and deserialize it into my Django model, through a RESTful API like Tastypie. I would like to check for any duplicate entries / validate data before updating the model.

What is the best practice and most seamless way to do this?

--

**JSON Output From Scraper (returns structured data)**

Note: exchange_id is the foreign key of the Exchange object in my Django model

{
"website": "http://www.igg.com/", 
"exchange_id": 1, 
"ticker": "8002", 
"full_name": "IGG Inc"
}

**Django model**

```
class Company (models.Model):
    ticker      = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    full_name   = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    exchange    = models.ForeignKey(Exchange, null=True)
    website     = models.URLField(null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ticker

    def website_url(self):
        if self.website:
            return '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (self.website, self.website)
        else:
            return ''
    website_url.allow_tags = True        

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Companies"
```

Comment: First of all, is this output data structured or unstructured? This fundamentally changes what kind of database you use. You need to add more information on this post about what you have, giving explicit examples, and describing what you want to do, using explicit examples, even if its a sketch of your idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that your app is private, and only you will have access to it. What you can do is implement django-restless with a model form.

```
from restless.http import Http201, Http400
from restless.views import Endpoint
from .forms import NewCompanyForm

class APIEndpoint(Endpoint):
    """
    Endpoint for posting json data to server
    """
    def post(self, request):
        company_form = NewCompanyForm(request.data)
        if company_form.is_valid():
            # Check for duplicate data
            # ...
            if unique:
                company_form.save()
                return Http201({"message": "Post successful"})
            else:
                return Http400(reason='Data was not unique')
        else:
            return Http400(reason='You did not post a valid input')
```

Also, here is an example app using this library, https://github.com/dobarkod/django-restless/blob/master/testproject/testapp/views.py

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you need some tool to post/put data to your Service via RestAPI. Look at [slumber](https://slumber.readthedocs.org). It very simple and very good interacting with tastypie.